# Using sets in python to find common letters from two strings

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, set

I am trying to write a program which basically takes two strings and find the common letters from both of them and finds the uncommon letters from them. It also has to find the digits and special characters you can in the strings and display them in the print command.

Here is my code

```
from string import ascii_letters
import re
import itertools

def main():
    s1 = input("Please enter string 1: ")
    s2 = input("Please enter string 2: ")
    ch=""
    lowercase_letters = [i for i in s1 if i.islower() and i in s2]
    #print(lowercase_letters)
    uppercase_letters = [i for i in s1 if i.isupper() and i in s2]
    # print(uppercase_letters)
    new_str=''.join(uppercase_letters+lowercase_letters)
    print("The set consisting of the upper and lowercase letters that are contained in both strings is: ", new_str)

    # stringFunction(s1, s2)
    # k= str(longest_common_substring(s1,s2))
    # print(k)

def stringFunction(s1, s2):
    l1=list(''.join(s1.split()))
    l2=list(''.join(s2.split()))
    return [x for x in l1 if x in l2]

    print (stringFunction)

def longest_common_substring(s1, s2):
   set1 = set(s1[begin:end] for (begin, end) in
              itertools.combinations(range(len(s1)+1), 2))
   set2 = set(s2[begin:end] for (begin, end) in
              itertools.combinations(range(len(s2)+1), 2))
   common = set1.intersection(set2)
   return str(common)

main()
```

The output should look like

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: I want to using two strings and find out :

a.  a set consisting of the upper- and lowercase letters that are contained in both strings.

b.  a set consisting of the upper- and lowercase letters that are not contained in either string.

c.  a set consisting of all non-letter characters contained in both strings.

Comment: That's nice. What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: Part b and c aren't working at all

Comment: Well, it looks like you haven't even attempted to solve them, as your current code doesn't contain anything that looks like it's even *trying* to address those points. Please [edit] your post to show what you have tried, including example input, expected output, actual output, and the **full text** of any tracebacks or errors. Stack Overflow is neither a forum nor a tutorial or code-writing service. I suggest you also take the [tour] and carefully read through the [help] to learn more about the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

@EDIT1: forgot that in python3.x print is a function.

@EDIT2: this was not part of the original request.

@EDIT3: formatted the output as later requested (I am not an expert in print formatting).

@EDIT4: modified the output to match the modified request

```
import string

def func(str1, str2):
    s1 = set(str1)
    s2 = set(str2)
    # requests are ambiguous "contained in both strings" can be either interpreted as intersections or union (i chose intersection)
    uni = s1.union(s2)
    letters_in_both_strings = [item for item in s1.intersection(s2) if item.isalpha()]
    non_letters_in_any_string = [item for item in uni if not item.isalpha()]
    all_letters = set(string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase)
    return letters_in_both_strings, all_letters.difference(uni), non_letters_in_any_string

str1 = input("Enter 1st string:")
str2 = input("Enter 2nd string:")
a, b, c = func(str1, str2)
print("|" + "".join(a) + "|\n|" + "".join(b) + "|\n|" + "".join(c) + "|\n")
```